# FineUploader batch upload with one invalid object

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

When a user uploads a batch of files with the FineUploader javascript plugin, and one of these objects has an invalid extension, the whole upload fails. I would like the process to proceed for all valid files. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have Fine Uploader simply ignore an invalid file, instead of stopping the entire upload.  This is covered in the documentation (in several places) such as in the [validation options section](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#validation-option).

For example:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    ...
    validation: {
        ....
        stopOnFirstInvalidFile: false
    }
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Wouldn't it be better to set the default to false?

Comment: Not necessarily.  This would introduce a breaking change.  The default was set to false initially to prevent a breaking change when this option was initially introduced, since the original behavior was to halt the submit if one file was invalid.